# How to find memory leak in a Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova

I have developed a phonegap application. Now I need to find memory leak in javascript code. I tried using instrument (supplied with xcode), but that doesn't help much in javascript. Could anyone please help on this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you won't be able to track the leaks which happens in javascript inside UIWebView, But you could avoid them by following some best practices in javascript programming.

These may help to avoid leaks in javascript,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/